# The execution failed. Please check error.log

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

When I uploaded a theme from outside on WordPress, after uploading it, when we are installing it, this error is coming. **The execution failed. Please check error.log**

Comment: And did you check the log to see what happened? You can enable wordpress debugging to help you with that! It may be the runtime, but it would have to be confirmed by consulting the log. https://wpforms.com/developers/how-to-enable-debugging-in-wordpress/

Comment: i dont have that much of tchnical language, can you please help me out